# Code takes too long to run , ends up crashing at times

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have this code which run successfully but only after a few moments. Sometimes  it even stops responding and then run normally again .Need help to run it faster without crashing. Here is the code

```
Sub DeleteCells()

    Dim R As Range
    'Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)
    Dim rng As Range
   Dim rngError As Range
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:G100")
   Set rngError = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

   If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    R.delete
   End If



For Each cell In rng
 If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then
  cell.EntireColumn.delete
 End If
     'delete means cells will move up after deleting that entire row
     'rngError.EntireRow.ClearContents means that the contents will clear, leaving a blank cell for that entire row
Next




End Sub
```

Comment: Note that "stops responding and the run normally again" is _not_ the same as crashing.  Please clarify whether your program is _also_ crashing, or if it's just freezing.

Comment: okay noted! Is there any ways to prevent it from happening? @paddy

Comment: Perhaps you have cascading updates happening as the cells are deleted.  If there's a way to disable formula/reference updates temporarily, I'd put my money on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting cells in a loop which can make it very slow. Is this what you are trying? This should be very fast... (**Untested**)

```
Sub DeleteCells()
    Dim rng As Range, rngError As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.Delete

    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        For i = 1 To 7 '<~~ Loop trough columns A to G
            '~~> Check if that column has any errors
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
                For j = 1 To 100 '<~~ Loop Through rows 1 to 100
                    If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                        '~~> Store The range to be deleted
                        If delRange Is Nothing Then
                            Set delRange = .Columns(i)
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Columns(i))
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

    '~~> Delete the range in one go
    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: it works but what if i want to change the columns to cells? and also make it flexible by deleting referenced data which is in another sheet instead of the same sheet? @Siddharth Rout

Comment: The reason I am using columns and not cells is because why do you want to loop through the cells in the same column which has been marked for deletion ;)? Notice the `Exit For`?

Comment: okay i see. got it! how do i incorporate other sheets apart from sheet 3 because i just used a single sheet to test the programme but in actual fact, my reference data are in several sheets not just sheet 3 alone!  @Siddharth Rout

Comment: Loop through the sheets. If you search stackoverflow, you can see lot of code for looping through the sheets